# Riot JS Text Search bug

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I am fairly new to Riot.js and MV* frameworks in general, so please bear with me.

https://plnkr.co/edit/QY3aoA4JH7ps65mRwGoB?p=preview

I have a list of 3 contacts.  I want to search for a contact by name using a text input field

```
<application>
  <input type="text" oninput={edit}>

  <h2>List of possible candidates</h2>
  <h3>{search}</h3>

  <div if={contact.name.toUpperCase().includes(search.toUpperCase())} each={contact in contacts}>
    {contact.name}
  </div>
  this.contacts = [
    {name : 'AMATO',     age : 20},
    {name : 'GROSSMAN',     age : 37},
    {name : 'OKAJA',   age : 18},
  ]

  search = '';

  edit(e){
    search = e.target.value
  }
</application>
```

This seems to work except in odd cases. For example, typing "j" or "ok" should return OKAJA, however instead it returns the second item in the array. What am I missing?  I am also open to better suggestions on formatting/syntax for the filter

Comment: Wow, I never tried mixing an `IF` with an `EACH`... I didn't know that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case of a problem that looks really complicated on the surface being solved by one simple line of code. Add `this.update()` to the `edit` function.

Minor note: in my fork of your Plunker and the code block below I used `this.search` instead of `search` to differentiate it in the JS code. This is *not* required, only `this.update()`.

```
<application>
    <input type="text" oninput={edit}>

    <h2>List of possible candidates</h2>
    <h3>{search}</h3>

    <div if={contact.name.toUpperCase().includes(this.search.toUpperCase())} each={contact in contacts}>
        {contact.name}
    </div>
    this.contacts = [
        {name : 'AMATO',     age : 20},
        {name : 'GROSSMAN',     age : 37},
        {name : 'OKAJA',   age : 18},
    ]

    this.search = '';

    edit(e){
        this.search = e.target.value
        this.update();
    }
</application>
```

[Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/EzMFa27lh4Upy1yjQsTW?p=preview)

Now, why did this happen "only in specific situations"? It seems like Riot.js was trying to check a given entry multiple times and as such it returned the wrong array of results for a given input set. I tried giving it an input set of size 5 with entries like ['abcde', 'bcdef', ..., 'efghi']. When queried for 'h', it checked index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4 in that order. It decided indices 1 and 3 contained g when it should've been 2, 3, 4. The takeaway from this is that you got lucky since you used such a small dataset. If the dataset got any larger, searching for any entry would fail spectacularly.